# How to avoid shorting the boards while using Probe or Multimeter?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, pcb-design, debugging

I have been working on multi layer boards at my work. Occasionally I short the boards because of probe hits a wrong spot. I measure various power rails and most of the output capacitors are 0201 and 1005 size.

Can people here provide some tips on avoiding shorts while probing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a microprobe. The smaller the width of the probe. The less likely you are to hit multiple pads from its radius alone
2. A sharp one is possible. If it can stab into the solder. It means its less likely to slip. In the past I have used sharp single point pogo pins for this end
3. Set up the measurement so you do not need to look away from where your probing. The moment it leaves your vision your hand positioning gets much worse. If you can hold a probe to a 0.1mm spot when seen. Your probably closer to 2mm unseen if you cannot stab the board for some feedback.
4. Use something similar to varnish or heatshrink to make sure only the very end of the probe is conductive. This will reduce the sides from touching other parts of the circuit.
5. In complex boards. While the power is off tack on some measurement wires. I prefer rigid ones like resistor legs. But for 01005 and 0201 size it would be more likely to be enamelled magnet wire to reduce the risk of tearing stuff off the board. Then you measure those wires.

And finally if you get any say in how the devices are made. Yell at the designers to include some uncoated vias for measuring the power rails with a small exclusion area of say 0.5mm. Makes things much easier for barely any change to layout. And as the probe can rest in the hole your less likely to drift.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
1.I'm using Agilent 10073C Probe which I think is sharp but I will try to find some sharper probes.
2.While measuring, I use microscope to look at the components and try to measure it.
3.What kind of varnish would you recommend? Any product name?
I wish I had some say in how designs are made, I am an entry level engineer.

Comment: 1. Recommend 0.3mm single point pogo pins. 2. So your eyes leave where your messuring. When you look up to read the meter. No easy workaround for this. Will need the feedback via mechanical means. 3. Just about any with a thin film. Even nail polish will do. That is what i have used in the past to make it easy to see where its cracking. 4. Testing costs money. Find the right person to suggest some test pads to. The designers may not think from a testing perspective. There is often a lot to keep in mind for these types of layout.

Answer (score 1):

1. I often solder a wire to the point I want to measure (while the board is not powered). 
   Then I attach the probe to the wire;
2. Sometimes I solder a pin from a pin header to the board that I can attach the probe to;
3. I anticipate debugging by adding test pin locations to the PCB while designing it;
4. If you have test pads, you can even solder a wire on to those;
5. Make sure that the "ground" connection of my probe can't easily loose grip and wander around - the tip rarely makes a short alone;
6. Make sure that the board is "floating" with regards to the scope's ground.  The scope very ground is likely connected to mains earth unless your scope is not connected to the mains earth!  A battery powered oscilloscope can help.  I've modded a low cost (low performance) DSO120 scope to be powered from a USB Power Bank by integrating a DC-DC booster in it.  You can also just isolate your circuit under test (while considering your safety of course).
7. Add some isolation tape to cover the conducting parts that you do not want to touch.

Comment: Hi le_top , thanks for your feedback.
1.I usually solder a wire to the inductor or cap in case of power rails or I even solder to some test point. 
2.Unfortunately I don’t have many test points or vias, maybe for the next design I should have to insist keeping some vias or test points.
3.What kind of insulation tape would your recommend? Can I use those tapes on top of some of the components ?

Comment: Classic "Electrical insulation tape" does the job - it is somewhat strechable too.  If the point that your are soldering your "test wire" does not allow a mechanically strong soler, fix the wire to the board using some tape, or loop your wire through a hole near the board or another hole.  You can use these tapes on tope of components.  I also add tape for better protection from the mains power on the board if I can't avoid the mains power.  Test pads are fairly easy to keep and are usefull for a bed of nails in production.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really much to say, beyond:

- Make sure you have a set of good, sharp probes (needle probes).
- Use magnification, unless you have excellent eyesight!
- Be careful

The first is probably the most important; You want a probe that will dig into the solder pad. The purpose if this is twofold:

- You're less likely to slip
- It will cut through the oxide layer / flux and make a good contact with less pressure, which also means you are less likely to slip. And less likely to damage those little 0201's.